# Alternative to lozenges

Tags: forms, webforms

[image]I am designing a form. One of the parameters can have multiple choices, and they need to display those choices, after they've been selected.

I used the lozenges pattern, as shown in the visuals. Note: last visual, "display" shows how the selections appear, in resting state.

Are there any alternatives to lozenges?

Maximum would be 20 chosen accounts.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with an alternative pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be called multi-select from a dropdown list. The chosen items could also function as a filter in some use cases. 
An alternative to lozenges is to show the **items in a list under the dropdown menu**, with a remove action.
 Another could be to have a **different visual treatment of the lozenges** as shown below.

Step 1: 
[image: Step 1 of multi select dropdown]
Step 2: 
[image: Step 2 of multi select dropdown]

Image credits: Daniel Sears on Dribbble: https://dribbble.com/shots/5457641-Multi-select